# Server system suddenly inaccessible from Internet, but accessible from LAN -- problem is NOT in the router

Tags: iptables

At first blush, this appears to be a simple problem, but unless I've missed something obvious (which is always possible), something weird is going on.

I was working remotely on a server system running in my office yesterday. I rebooted it after moving some files, and it suddenly stopped responding to Internet requests -- SSH, HTTP/HTTPS, IMAP, everything. However, I could still access it if I SSH'd into another machine on the same LAN, then SSH'd to that server. Rebooting the server again changed nothing.

My first thought was that something had gotten screwed up with the firewall on that system, but...

```
me@nas:~$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for me: 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8022
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10024
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8099

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

(I've also temporarily disabled the firewall on that system. No change.)

To make absolutely certain it wasn't the router, I upgraded the firmware on it (I've been needing to do that anyway) and re-entered all the settings manually, including the port-forwarding settings for that machine. Again, no change.

I can't blame the ISP, because I can still SSH into other machines on the network through the same IP address and a slightly different port. I've tried the "Shields Up!" service from grc.com; it sees the other machine's SSH port, but *all* the ports for this server appear as "stealth."

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04. The only idea I have left is that I might have automatically told it to update the software before I rebooted, and something new might have changed a setting, but I think I'd rebooted a couple times already since doing any upgrades.

What else can I look at?

---

LATER EDIT:

After a few days, the problem recurred, and the original solution I'd found (power-cycling the system instead of rebooting remotely) did *not* fix it. After much tearing-out of hair, I stumbled onto another solution: simply calling `sudo dhclient` fixed the problem every time. Adding that into the root user's `crontab` ("@reboot /sbin/dhclient") seems to have solved it permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Oh %#@$%#$... it suddenly occurred to me that although I'd rebooted several times, I hadn't actually powered the machine off. Did so, left it off for thirty seconds, restarted... and suddenly everything was working again. :-(</s>

No idea what cosmic ray could have caused the problem, but it's fixed now.

See updated description of the problem, above.

Comment: I would advise deleting the question then.

Comment: I was under the impression that solved problems should be left on the system, so that people searching for answers later can find them. I regularly reboot remotely, and I suspect a lot of other people who usually administer machines through SSH do as well, so I believe this could help people.